# Incorrect equation numbering between align and case environment

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I am facing problem in equation referencing. I am using two equation environments,One is align and second is cases. Below is the code given:

```
Cost Function of Dual Dispersion MCMA is:\\
\begin{align}
J_{DD-MCMA}=&E\left[(|y_R(n )|^2 - R_{VR})^2\right]+\\
&E\left[(|y_I(n )|^2 - R_{VI})^2\right] \nonumber
\label{cf:ddmcma}
\end{align}

The dispersion constants RVR and RVI is chosen based on following criteria as given automatically during the execution of algorithm :

\begin{align}
R_{VR}&=
\begin{cases}
RR1     &\text{if $y_{R}(n)^2\:\leq\: RR1$ } \\
RR2     &\text{if $y_{R}(n)^2\:\leq\: RR2$ } \\
RR2     &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \\
R_{VI}&=
\begin{cases}
RI1     &\text{if $y_{I}(n)^2\:\leq\: RI1$ } \\
RI2     &\text{if $y_{I}(n)^2\:\leq\: RI2$ } \\
RI2     &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\label{dc:ddmcma}
\end{align}
```

when i tried to refer it just like

```
\par In order to obtain the stochastic gradient adaptive algorithm tap update equation, we differentiate the cost function in equation \eqref{cf:ddmcma} with respect to equalizer tap weight vector w and approximating the expectation with
the instantaneous values gives
```

the output of LATEX print the equation number of equation in case environment as I have refer the equation number to be displayed from align tormentor equation.
e.g if align environment equation number is **11** and case environment equation number is **12** and **13** then the equation referencing displays **12** instead of **11**. Please help.

Comment: the first equation i would write: `\begin{equation}\label{cf:ddmcma} \begin{split} J_{DD-MCMA} & = E\left[(|y_R(n )|^2 - R_{VR})^2\right]+\\
&\quad E\left[(|y_I(n )|^2 - R_{VI})^2\right]\end{split}\end{equation}`. with this you will obtain nicer align of equation number and working referencing. welcome to tex.se!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the `\nonumber` command that is placed before the `\label` command in your first eqiuation.

Try like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Cost Function of Dual Dispersion MCMA is:
\begin{align}
J_{DD-MCMA}=&E\left[(|y_R(n )|^2 - R_{VR})^2\right]+\label{cf:ddmcma}\\
&E\left[(|y_I(n )|^2 - R_{VI})^2\right] \nonumber
\end{align}

The dispersion constants RVR and RVI is chosen based on following criteria as given automatically during the execution of algorithm :
\begin{align}
R_{VR}=&
\begin{cases}
RR1     &\text{if $y_{R}(n)^2\:\leq\: RR1$ } \\
RR2     &\text{if $y_{R}(n)^2\:\leq\: RR2$ } \\
RR2     &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \\
R_{VI}=&
\begin{cases}
RI1     &\text{if $y_{I}(n)^2\:\leq\: RI1$ } \\
RI2     &\text{if $y_{I}(n)^2\:\leq\: RI2$ } \\
RI2     &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\label{dc:ddmcmb}
\end{align}

Eq \ref{cf:ddmcma} and \ref{dc:ddmcmb}
\end{document}
```

Now the first reference is about the number (1) and not the unnumbered (so next) equation...

Comment: Please replace `=&` with `&=`. Doing so will improve the spacing around the `=` symbol noticeably. And please eliminate the paragraph break before the second instance of `\begin{align}`. Finally, do eliminate the doube-backslash after `Cost Function of Dual Dispersion MCMA is:`.

Comment: The first `align` should be `equation` with `split`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `\label` after a `\nonumber` line (that you, hence the name, cannot reference by number). Just put it into (or before) the line that is numbered:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Cost Function of Dual Dispersion MCMA is:\\
\begin{align}
J_{DD-MCMA}={}&E\left[(|y_R(n )|^2 - R_{VR})^2\right]+\label{cf:ddmcma}\\
&E\left[(|y_I(n )|^2 - R_{VI})^2\right] \nonumber
\end{align}

The dispersion constants RVR and RVI is chosen based on following criteria as given automatically during the execution of algorithm :

\begin{align}
R_{VR}&=
\begin{cases}
RR1     &\text{if $y_{R}(n)^2\:\leq\: RR1$ } \\
RR2     &\text{if $y_{R}(n)^2\:\leq\: RR2$ } \\
RR2     &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \\
R_{VI}&=
\begin{cases}
RI1     &\text{if $y_{I}(n)^2\:\leq\: RI1$ } \\
RI2     &\text{if $y_{I}(n)^2\:\leq\: RI2$ } \\
RI2     &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\label{dc:ddmcma}
\end{align}

\par In order to obtain the stochastic gradient adaptive algorithm tap update equation, we differentiate the cost function in equation \eqref{cf:ddmcma} with respect to equalizer tap weight vector w and approximating the expectation with
the instantaneous values gives

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Please replace `=&` with `&=`. Doing so will improve the spacing around the `=` symbol noticeably.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the hint, didn't see it, just c&p'd it. This will lead to the probably undesired effect of a shifted second line. I instead used `={}&` now. Hope this suffices your demand :)

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have already pointed out, the `\nonumber` directive inside teh first `align` environment is the immediate cause of the problem.

In addition to omitting the undesirable `\nonumber` directive, you may want to think of replacing the entire first `align` environment, as line-breaking is neiter necessary nor required. On the other hand, do spend some type to typeset various constants and acronyms (e.g., `DD-MCMA`) more attratively.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E} % expectation operator (?)
\newcommand\vn[1]{\textit{#1}} % "variable name"
\begin{document}

Cost function of Dual Dispersion MCMA is:
\begin{equation} \label{cf:ddmcma}
J_{\vn{DD-MCMA}}=
\E\bigl[(|y^{}_{R}(n)|^2 - R_{\vn{VR}})^2\bigr]+
\E\bigl[(|y^{}_{I}(n)|^2 - R_{\vn{VI}})^2\bigr] 
\end{equation}
The dispersion constants $R_{\vn{VR}}$ and
$R_{\vn{VI}}$ are chosen based on following 
criteria as given automatically during the 
execution of algorithm:
\begin{align}
R_{\vn{VR}} &=
\begin{cases}
RR1     &\text{if $y^{}_{R}(n)^2\leq RR1$} \\
RR2     &\text{if $y^{}_{R}(n)^2\leq RR2$} \\
RR2     &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \label{dc:ddmcmb} \\
R_{\vn{VI}} &=
\begin{cases}
RI1     &\text{if $y^{}_{I}(n)^2\leq RI1$} \\
RI2     &\text{if $y^{}_{I}(n)^2\leq RI2$} \\
RI2     &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \label{dc:ddmcmc}
\end{align}

Equations \eqref{cf:ddmcma} and \eqref{dc:ddmcmc} \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, even better than my complication suggested in my comment above :-)